# TypeError when trying to convert a row to a float as to append into a list

Tags: python

I am trying to append every second row from a dataset into a separate list. But I get a `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'`when trying to convert each row into a float so I can do this.

```
x_data = [random.sample(range(80), 20)]*1000
y_data = [random.sample(range(80), 20)]*1000

data = [x_data,y_data]

n = 0
for row in data :
    if n == 0 :
        n+=1
        continue
    x_data = []
    y_data = []
    for (x,y) in [(0,1),(2,3), (4,5), (6,7), (8,9), (10,11), (12,13), (14,15), (16,17), (18,19), (20,21), (22,23), (24,25), (26,27), (28,29), (30,31), (32,33), (34,35), (36,37), (38,39)] : 
        xcoord = float(row[x]) #Error occurs in this line
        ycoord = float(row[y])
        if xcoord >= 5 :
            x_data.append(xcoord)
            y_data.append(ycoord)
```

I tried to change `float(row[x])` to `list(map(float(row[x]))` but get the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x_data` and `y_data` are list of lists. `random.sample()` will return a list for you and you are currently putting that list inside another list and `* 1000` which will just repeat that inner list a 1000 times. I think you need to simply make the following changes:

```
x_data = random.sample(range(80), 20)*1000
y_data = random.sample(range(80), 20)*1000
```